# Select a specific element which has multiple classes?

Tags: html, css

I want to select a specific element identified by three classes. Is this possible? For example, some `div` element has three classes: `alpha`, `beta` and `charlie`. Some other elements have one or two of these classes also, but I just want my code to affect elements with all three of them, like:

```
.alpha beta charlie { ... }
```

Is this possible?

The above example is completely random, I know it doesn't work, but I just wanted to depict what I'm planning to achieve. I'm still trying to learn CSS completely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do like below **[DEMO:](https://jsfiddle.net/a3Lsvz4r/)**

**CSS:**

```
.alpha.beta.gamma{color:red;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="alpha beta gamma">
   hello
</div>
<div class="alpha beta gamma delta">
   hello
</div>
<div class="alpha beta  delta">
   hello
</div>
```

This will change color to all the divs which has those three classes together.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSS rules looks like:

```
<style>
.alpha { .... }
.beta  {..... }
.charlie {.....}
</style>
```

And your html like:

```
<div id=div1 class='alpha beta charlie'><div>
<div id=div2 class='alpha beta charlie'><div>
```

Then both divs will have all the rules from all 3 classes.

If you then have an additional div like:

```
<div id=div3 class='alpha beta'><div>
```

That will only have the rules only from classes called alpha and beta.

Comment: Change `style` to `class` and you'll be correct.

Comment: Ooopss.... I think it's time to sleep at midnight rather then hanging out on StackOverflow :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to write your selector using the three class names:

```
 .alpha.beta.charlie {}
```

When they are attached, it will style any tag with all 3 of those classes:

```
<element class="alpha beta charlie">
```